# If I add an additional column to handle special values, how will this impact my table size?

Tags: postgresql, table

I have a table `TABLE1` with 400,000 row (by now) that has 20 columns.

I have a column `DETAIL` that usually stores 100 to 300 characters, that's why its size is 1024, but I have an special case. I need to store 1900 chars for one row only.

The solution that I found is creating another column, `DETAIL2` to store remaining characters, but I'm afraid that this will cause my table size to increase a lot (just one row would have `DETAIL2`, others will be `NULL`).

Is this the right solution or is there a better way to store the special case?

Comment: Just increase the size of the column or change it to `text`

Answer (score 2):

Change the datatype of `Detail` to `VARCHAR(2000)` or `TEXT`*.  This will be enough to handle your 1900 length value plus a little padding for future exceptions.  This will add no additional overhead beyond the additional storage needed for that particular row.

If you add another column you will add 1 byte to all of the rows (which isn't a big deal) but now you have to contend with two columns with different names but the same purpose.

Postgres documentation explains storage requirements in more detail:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html

*The `TEXT` datatype is not ANSI compliant, if you do use it understand the implications.

Comment: I'll upvote if you change your recommendation to `text`. It makes no sense to set an arbitrary limit: next week, someone will want to store 2000 characters.

Comment: I will update my answer to "or `TEXT`".  `VARCHAR` is compliant with SQL standards, `TEXT` is not.